# Touchpad too sensitive on LXDE

Tags: lxde, touchpad

I've recently installed LXLE (with LXDE desktop environment), and I keep having problems where my mouse clicks are being triggered while typing on the keyboard.

Basically "Mouse Click" is super sensitive which means that in the middle of writing it clicks and chooses another dialog (almost constantly).

How do I make this less sensitive (never happened on Windows)?

**Edit** 
If it's helpful, I'm using a Fujitsu LIFEBOOK NH751

Added the output of xinput; dmesg | grep pnp (the device part):

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02E3                           id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Fujitsu FUJ02B1                           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ FJ Camera                                 id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: see if https://blog.laimbock.com/2014/11/23/howto-fix-a-too-sensitive-touchpad-on-linux/comment-page-1/ or https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad is of any help in reducing sensitivity.

Comment: Also look at the `-i` option in `man syndaemon`.

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem I get too so I turn it off by using this

```
# Turn off touch pad
# placed in ~/.xproflie also 
exec xinput set-prop 12 "Device Enabled" 0
exec synclient touchpadoff=1 
exec synclient VertEdgeScroll=0 
exec synclient TapButton1=0
exec synclient TapButton2=0
exec synclient TapButton3=0
```

you can stick this is your bashrc file to trun it on and off

```
alias TT='touchpad-toggle'

###

function touchpad-toggle {

# toggle synaptic touchpad on/off

# get current state
SYNSTATE=$(synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff | awk '{ print $3 }')

# change to other state
if [ $SYNSTATE = 0 ]; then
    synclient touchpadoff=1
    echo "touchpad OFF"
elif [ $SYNSTATE = 1 ]; then
    synclient touchpadoff=0
    echo "touchpad ON"
else
    echo "Couldn't get touchpad status from synclient"
    exit 1
fi
 }

####

alias TT
```

you can google synclient touch pad linux for key words to find out more

Comment: So this turns it off entirely? I wanted something do decrease click sensitivity (saw on Arch something with FingerHigh FingerLow but couldn't find an equivalent on LXLE), because this doesn't happen on all Desktop Environments..

Comment: yep tunrs it off completely, there is a set up out there to turn it off when typing, it is your pad right and left clicks we're talking about yes, not the mouse itself? Read this it may help give you more options 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

Comment: technically it's the tapping on the pad itself, that is being identified as "left click" while I'm typing..

Comment: that is why people came up with a function that stops the pad from receiving input from the pad, mostly because these types of people use a Mouse to do their bidding and not the pad. it is of no use to them.